# OData: Trips query error casting complex types

Tags: odata

I'm trying to request this query:

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('russellwhyte')/AddressInfo/Microsoft.OData.SampleService.Models.TripPin.AirportLocation
```

So, I'm trying to get all `AirportLocation` from `People('russellwhyte')`. However, I'm getting this error message:

```
"error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Type cast segment 'Microsoft.OData.SampleService.Models.TripPin.AirportLocation' after a collection which is not of entity type is not allowed.",
    "innererror": {...
}
```

This is the `Location` complex type related schema:

```
<ComplexType Name="Location" OpenType="true">
    <Property Name="Address" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="City" Type="Microsoft.OData.SampleService.Models.TripPin.City" Nullable="false" />
</ComplexType>
<ComplexType Name="EventLocation" BaseType="Microsoft.OData.SampleService.Models.TripPin.Location" OpenType="true">
    <Property Name="BuildingInfo" Type="Edm.String" />
</ComplexType>
<ComplexType Name="AirportLocation" BaseType="Microsoft.OData.SampleService.Models.TripPin.Location" OpenType="true">
     <Property Name="Loc" Type="Edm.GeographyPoint" Nullable="false" SRID="4326" />
</ComplexType>
```

So `Location` complex type is the base type of `AirportLocation` and `EventLocation`.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe The trip service didn't have such functionality implemented. However, it does supports in OData.

Basically, in convention routing, you should add the corresponding methods in the controller. For example, If you have the follow inheritance:

```
Address
CnAddress : Address
UsAddress : Address
```

entity type `Customer` has property named `Locations` with type `IList<Address>`

you should have method named `GetLocationsOfCnAddress` or `GetLocationsOfUsAddress` in the `CustomersController : ODataController`

Comment: Could you provide me any stuff helping documentation explaining why should I have a `GetLocationsOfCnAddress` and a `GetLocationsOfUsAddress`? By other hand, do you know any service really supports such functionality?

Comment: You can find some docs about the convention routing: http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-02-built-in-routing-conventions. But it doesn't mention the property cast. Maybe you can refer to the codes: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Routing/Conventions/PropertyRoutingConvention.cs#L65-L67